# how to convert the column with numeric and date format into date type?

Tags: r

need to convert the column into date

```
names<-c("tom", "dick", "harry", "mary", "susie")
date_1<-c(15127, 15034, 15034, 15141, 15013)
date_2<-c(15155, 15062, 15064, 03/05/2019, 15041)
date_3<-c(15185, 15091, 15092, 01/20/2019, 15069)
df<-data.frame(names, date_1, date_2, date_3)


mutate(df, date_3 = as.Date(date_3, format= "%d/%m/%Y")


names<-c("tom", "dick", "harry", "mary", "susie")
date_1<-c(15127, 15034, 15034, 15141, 15013)
date_2<-c(15155, 15062, 15064, 03/05/2019, 15041)
date_3<-c(15185, 15091, 15092, 01/20/2019, 15069)
df<-data.frame(names, date_1, date_2, date_3)


mutate(df, date_3 = as.Date(date_3, format= "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Error: unexpected symbol in:
"       mutate(df, date_3 = as.Date(date_3, format= "%d.%m.%Y")
                      df"

Comment: What is your expected output ? Seems like you have just copied your data and attempt twice.

Comment: I think your data or example might be a bit mangled. `01/20/2019` is `1 ÷ 20 ÷ 2019` and not a string in the way you have posted. Try wrapping it in `""` like  `"01/20/2019"`. You also seemingly have numbers and text inside the same string. If you can provide an expected result as Ronak suggests that will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for Date. Install zoo library first

```
install.packages("zoo")

library(zoo)

date_1 <- as.Date(date_1) 

date_2 <- as.Date(date_2) 

date_3 <- as.Date(date_3)

df <- data.frame(names,date_1,date_2,date_3)
```

after that you can convert any format %Y-%m-%d